# MediaWiki Ask Query

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I have created two pages in a MediaWiki: John, and Category:Smith (note that the page Smith is a category page). Both pages were part of the Category:Person. When I run an Ask query to return all the pages that are under the category Person, only the page John is returned.
{{#ask: [[:Category:Person]] | ?label}}. It seems to me that the Ask query does not return pages that are category pages.

Any comment or solution to this problem?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't need the : before Category `{{#ask:[[Category:Person]]}}`.

Comment: (Using `:Category`, you ask for properties from the category page itself only.)

Answer (score 1):

The “Semantic MediaWiki” way to do it would be to query for properties, rather than categories. You could make both John and Category:Smith have the property `[[Is a::Person]]`, and make a query like `{{#ask:[[Is a::Person]] |?label}}`.

There are valid uses for categories even with SMW, of course, but it is hard to give you advice on your semantic structure without seeing the whole picture. In your example, though, it seems to be like Smith is a surname, not a person, and thus should no be a subcategory to Category:Persons. Rather, you would normally have all persons directly in Category:Persons, and add properties like `Has surname::Smith`, etc, so that you could ask questions like `{{#ask: [[Category:Persons]] [[Has surname::Smith]] [[Age::>36]]}}`

Comment: Thank you for your response. In the example above I meant that John and Smith are completely different people. I agree, the project I am working on uses Categories incorrectly (basically every page is a Category page)

Comment: Ok, but even if you are stuck with a categories-as-content-pages kind of solution (I've been there too...), you can still put properties on the category pages, and query on them! Then the category pages will behave as normal pages